# google script on edit

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

У меня есть два скрипта

Первый под написанную функцию

```js
function onEdit(event) 
{
    SmartDataValidation(event);
}
```

Второй под подстановку даты изменений:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
    var sheetName = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var idCol = event.range.getColumn();
    var idRow = event.range.getRow();
    if (idCol === 13 && sheetName === 'Заказы'){
        sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol +8).setValue(new Date().toString());
    }
};
```

Но они не работают вместе, перекрывают друг друга. Как сделать так, чтобы работали оба скрипта?

Comment: Решилось просто function onEdit(event) 
{
  
  SmartDataValidation(event);
  var sheetName = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var idCol = event.range.getColumn();
    var idRow = event.range.getRow();
  if (idCol === 13 && sheetName === 'Заказы'){
    sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol +8).setValue(new Date().toString());
      }
  
}